# Explanation of two slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, string-theory, elementary-particles

Whilst going through 'a brief history of time' ,I faced difficulty in understanding the two slit experiment. How can individual electrons cause fringes?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point :) - it is hard to "understand", it's not intuitive - that's what makes the fact, that it's true, so intereseting

Comment: Can you include the passage where it says individual electrons cause fringes in your question? Then, I can give you a more thorough answer.